# MySQL insert on duplicate update multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I have the following table "texts"

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+
| txt_id  | txt_lang_id | txt_section | txt_code  | txt_value          | 
+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+
|    1    |     1       | home        | txt_title | Home               |
|    2    |     1       | home        | txt_btn   | I'm a button       |
|    3    |     1       | home        | txt_welc  | Welcome to home    |
etc...
```

I have multiple databases, one for each company, and a master database where the texts are created, besides, in each company, the administrator can customize your texts.

My idea is to create a query that inserts the new texts created in each database, and if it already exists to update the value.

It is possible to make the query  `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`  Have several conditions like `txt_lang_id = 1 AND txt_section = 'home' AND txt_code = 'txt_title' SET txt_value = 'New home'`

My idea is to be that way, because the same function would use it for other tables, such as configuration, which is a table that starts empty, and is populated as the administrator of company changes the default options, so the auto id is not always in the same order for all companies.

It is possible to do something like this, or rather I look for the way that the rows are always in the same order. Thanks.

Comment: your question is not very clear

Comment: what fields define your primary and if any unique keys?  From the question, seems like txt_lang_id, txt_section, txt_code and txt_value make up the uniqueness of the record is that right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UPDATE` with `CASE`, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE txt_value = 
(CASE WHEN txt_lang_id = 1 AND txt_section = 'home' 
AND txt_code = 'txt_title' THEN 'New home' else txt_value end);
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e44820/1/0)**.